# Python sub-dictionary/list within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to create a sub-dictionary within a dictionary? An example would be a dictionary of Cities in a state, Streets in that city, and finally house numbers on that street? I am building a circuit configuration building program in which I have programmed our IDF Locations and gear in that IDF. I then use that dictionary to generate list items for a MenuBox in Tkinter. My over all goal is to be able to associate things like IP address, Uplink ports, and Rack Locations to that gear, but have that information be hidden to the user. The way I have it setup now is that I simply append all that information to the end of the string that represents the gear, and then use string.split() to pull the info into corresponding variables. The issue with this is that everything is visible to the user and it looks messy. Here is an example of how I would like to set it up

```
dict = {'Toledo': ['Main': ['1234', '4321'], 'First st': ['312', '412', '1234'], 'Second st': ['1243, '3213', 4123']],
    'Cleveland': ['Third st': ['1234', '593], 'Front st': ['321', '467', '12340']],
    'Cincinnati': ['Bishop': ['5901', '1234'], 'Wells': ['1234', '1234', '8842]]}
strAddress = tk.StringVar()
strStreet = tk.StringVar()
optCity = tk.OptionMenu(master, strAddress, *dict.keys())
entCust = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=strStreet)
print(strAddress.get(strStreet.get()[1] + ' ' + strStreet.get() + ', ' + strAddress.get())
```

This would print out "1234 Main, Toledo" if the user selected Toledo from the option menu and typed Main into the entry box. Please let me know if you need more information or if my code is wrong, I am very new to python

Comment: You are using `['Main': ...]` instead of `{'Main':...}` for one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
data = {
    "Toledo": {
        "Main": [12, 23]
    }, 
    "Cleveland": {
        "Third st": ['1234', '593']
    }
}
```

is an example. You can also create it like this:

```
data = dict()
data["Toledo"] = {
    "Main": [12, 23]
}
data["Cleveland"] = {
    "Third st": ['1234', '593']
}
```

NB. Don't use `dict` as a variable name. `dict` is a reserved keyword for the builtin dictionary type.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you've got wrong is that you tried to build a list instead of a dict (used [] instead of {} for the secondary dict).
You can do this for instance:

`states = {'usa': {'GA': 'Atlanta'}, 'Canada': {'Ontario': 'Toronto'}}`